# StackoverflowException when compiling query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We rarely get StackOverflowExceptions when compiling LINQ to Entity queries. These exceptions happen completely random and we found no way to reproduce it. Even running same code again after getting the exception, it usually works fine. So far we thought this might be related to the complexity of the queries, but now we got it on a really simple one:

```
 var prozQuery = ctx.Set<Prozess>().Where(x => x.Id = prozess.Id);

var titelQuery = prozQuery
    .SelectMany(x => x.Personen)
    .Where(x => x.BssPersonenrolleEnu == 1 || x.BssPersonenrolleEnu == 5)
    .Select(x => x.Person)
    .SelectMany(pt => pt.BssTitel);

var titelOrgaQuery = titelQuery.Select(x => x.AusstellendeOrganisation).Where(x => x != null);

var titelOrganisationen = titelOrgaQuery.ToList() // Overflow happens here
```

Last frames on Stacktrace:

```
000000f13aa93470 00007ffe0c5ffa74 [FaultingExceptionFrame: 000000f13aa93470] 
000000f13aa97748 00007ffe0c5ffa74 [HelperMethodFrame: 000000f13aa97748] 
000000f13aa97870 00007ffdec2576a1 System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32)
000000f13aa978d0 00007ffdec2575a9 System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char*, Int32)
000000f13aa97920 00007ffdec257539 System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendHelper(System.String)
000000f13aa97950 00007ffdec25f30e System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(System.String)
000000f13aa979a0 00007ffd97b9a7c4 System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.TypeUsage.BuildIdentity(System.Text.StringBuilder)
000000f13aa97a00 00007ffd9969bdfc System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.RowType.GetRowTypeIdentityFromProperties(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.InitializerMetadata)
000000f13aa97a70 00007ffd9969b9fe System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.RowType..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.InitializerMetadata)
000000f13aa97ac0 00007ffd9969b957 System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.TypeHelpers.CreateRowType(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1>, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.InitializerMetadata)
000000f13aa97b30 00007ffd9976574f System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.TypeHelpers.CreateKeyRowType(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityTypeBase)
000000f13aa97ba0 00007ffd99765520 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.ITreeGenerator.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbRefExpression)
000000f13aa97bf0 00007ffd996a939a System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.ITreeGenerator.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbNewInstanceExpression)
000000f13aa97c90 00007ffd99663f25 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.ITreeGenerator.VisitExprAsScalar(System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpression)
000000f13aa97cd0 00007ffd996609cf System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.ITreeGenerator.GenerateStandardProject(System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression)
000000f13aa97d20 00007ffd9965ed67 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.ITreeGenerator..ctor(System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbQueryCommandTree, System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.DiscriminatorMap)
000000f13aa97da0 00007ffd996a8c5a System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView.GetInternalTree(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Command)
000000f13aa97df0 00007ffd99669a88 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ExpandView(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.IsOfOp ByRef)
000000f13aa97e60 00007ffd996696a6 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.IsOfOp ByRef)
000000f13aa97eb0 00007ffd99669606 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa97ee0 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa97f40 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa97fc0 00007ffd99669134 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98020 00007ffd9e4c4be9 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.BuildRelPropertyExpression(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelProperty, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa980d0 00007ffd996acc54 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor+d__54.MoveNext()
000000f13aa98140 00007ffd996ab8a3 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.NewEntityOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa981f0 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98250 00007ffd99666f95 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98280 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa982e0 00007ffd99666f95 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98310 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98370 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa983f0 00007ffd99667847 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98470 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa984d0 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98550 00007ffd996ab40a System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanViewOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa985a0 00007ffd996696b1 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.IsOfOp ByRef)
000000f13aa985f0 00007ffd99669606 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98620 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98680 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98700 00007ffd99669134 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98760 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa987c0 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98840 00007ffd99667847 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa988c0 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98920 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa989a0 00007ffd996ab40a System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanViewOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa989f0 00007ffd996696b1 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.IsOfOp ByRef)
000000f13aa98a40 00007ffd99669606 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98a70 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98ad0 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98b50 00007ffd99669134 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98bb0 00007ffd9e4c4be9 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.BuildRelPropertyExpression(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelProperty, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98c60 00007ffd996acc54 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor+d__54.MoveNext()
000000f13aa98cd0 00007ffd996ab8a3 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.NewEntityOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98d80 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98de0 00007ffd99666f95 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98e10 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98e70 00007ffd99666f95 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98ea0 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98f00 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa98f80 00007ffd99667847 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99000 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99060 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa990e0 00007ffd996ab40a System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanViewOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99130 00007ffd996696b1 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.IsOfOp ByRef)
000000f13aa99180 00007ffd99669606 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa991b0 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99210 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99290 00007ffd99669134 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa992f0 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99350 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa993d0 00007ffd99667847 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99450 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa994b0 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99530 00007ffd996ab40a System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanViewOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99580 00007ffd996696b1 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.IsOfOp ByRef)
000000f13aa995d0 00007ffd99669606 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99600 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99660 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa996e0 00007ffd99669134 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99740 00007ffd9e4c4be9 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.BuildRelPropertyExpression(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelProperty, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa997f0 00007ffd996acc54 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor+d__54.MoveNext()
000000f13aa99860 00007ffd996ab8a3 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.NewEntityOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99910 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99970 00007ffd99666f95 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa999a0 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99a00 00007ffd99666f95 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99a30 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99a90 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99b10 00007ffd99667847 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99b90 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99bf0 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99c70 00007ffd996ab40a System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanViewOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99cc0 00007ffd996696b1 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.IsOfOp ByRef)
000000f13aa99d10 00007ffd99669606 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99d40 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99da0 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99e20 00007ffd99669134 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99e80 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99ee0 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99f60 00007ffd99667847 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa99fe0 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa9a040 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa9a0c0 00007ffd996ab40a System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanViewOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa9a110 00007ffd996696b1 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.IsOfOp ByRef)
000000f13aa9a160 00007ffd99669606 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa9a190 00007ffd99667016 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa9a1f0 00007ffd996678a5 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa9a270 00007ffd99669134 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa9a2d0 00007ffd9e4c4be9 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.BuildRelPropertyExpression(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RelProperty, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node)
000000f13aa9a380 00007ffd996acc54 System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor+d__54.MoveNext()
```

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Nope, the overflow became rarer, but no idea why it happened or why it happens less now.